# How to prevent log file truncation with python logging module?

Tags: python, logging

I need to use python logging module to print debugging info to a file with statements like:

```
logging.debug(something)
```

The file is truncated (i am assuming - by the logging module) and the messages get deleted before I can see them - how can that be prevented?

Here is my logging config:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.DEBUG,
    format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    filename = '/tmp/my-log.txt',
    filemode = 'w'
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#simple-examples)

> If you run the script repeatedly, the additional log messages are appended to the file. **To create a new file each time, you can pass a filemode argument to basicConfig() with a value of 'w'**. Rather than managing the file size yourself, though, it is simpler to use a RotatingFileHandler.

To prevent overwriting the file, you should not set `filemode` to `'w'`, or [set it to `'a'`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) (that is the default setting anyway).

I believe that you are simply overwriting the file.